# How can I send multiple HTTP requests in parallel with javascript and wait for all of them to finish in a synchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, wait, chromium

I'm trying to send multiple HTTP requests in parallel using JavaScript. However I need to wait for all of them to complete before continuing further script execution. In the way that it is setup I have to block the main thread until all requests have finished (See the section "Background" for the explanation). Is there any way to do this in a clean way?

### Example

```js
function sendRequest(url) {
    let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

let request1 = sendRequest("https://ressource1.com");
let request2 = sendRequest("https://ressource2.com");
let request3 = sendRequest("https://ressource3.com");
let request3 = sendRequest("https://ressource4.com");
// wait for the requests [request1, request2, request3, request4].

// only continue after all requests are done
```

### Background

I'm trying to write a PDF-Exporter using a headless chromium client. The goal of the project is to fetch data from a remote server. This data should then be rendered in HTML and exported as a PDF. The problem is that the PDF-Export with the `--print-to-pdf` flag exports the PDF when:

1. The document state is `complete`
2. and all synchronous code has finished execution

The document state only changes when all synchronous code from the previous state has finished. It is therefor possible to prevent the early export by waiting until all requests have responded. This is the problem how do I wait for multiple async requests to finish in a synchronous function?

### What I've tested so far

1. The state change doesn't wait for: `Promise`, `Timeouts` and `async functions`. I've tested these options and couldn't find any solutions
2. Sending the requests synchronous one after the other works but is four times slower then sending then in parallel. (This will not be viable for larger projects)
3. Actively waiting for all requests to finish. This also works but takes up a lot of unnecessary performance.
4. `Promise.all()` and `fetch()` also don't work because they just return a promise without pausing the execution.

---

I hope the explanation is understandable. Thank you very much for taking the time to read this :)

Comment: Take a look on Promise.All()

Comment: Hi, have a look at Fetch(), it returns a Promise : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch and Promise.all() returns a Promise resolved when all of Promises passed are resolved : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I've tested `Promise.All()` it just returns a new promise. The thread it self doesn't wait until all of them have finished. So that is again something that doesn't work :/.  I'll have a look into Fetch() :)

Comment: Update `fetch()` also doesn't work. The request is send out and the execution continues as usual without waiting.

Comment: Use `Promise.all().then(() => {` and then at the end of your code add `})`